# Is it safe to get a flu shot when living with an elderly person?

Tags: vaccination, influenza

I share a house with a healthy nonagenarian. I know the flu can be dangerous for people of advanced age, so I'm considering getting a flu shot this year.

Is this a good idea? Are there any risks I could pose after being vaccinated? I've heard (anecdotally) that you can be mildly contagious for a brief time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of flu vaccine - inactivated influenza vaccine (which uses 'killed' influenza virus) and live-attenuated vaccine (which uses a more mild virus that should be asymptomatic).

[According to the CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/flu/professionals/vaccination/vaccine_safety.htm), among the contraindications for the live-attenuated vaccine is: "Children aged <2 years or adults aged ≥50 years". This is likely because, as you mentioned, it's possible for you to shed said live virus and infect others, and while the attenuated flu strain *should* be harmless, it's not a great idea to test that on high risk groups.

The inactivated vaccine carries no such contraindication. It is however something you should certainly bring up with your medical professional.

Comment: +0 because this answer includes medical jargon such as the words "asymptomatic" and "contraindication".  It's otherwise a very good answer though.  If you do [edit] the jargon out, feel free to ping me (unforgettableid at gmail dot com) and to flag this comment as "obsolete".

Comment: @unforgettableid Nope. Others may of course edit as they wish.